# save the last 2 increments of a for loop

Tags: python, dataframe, loops, save

I have my loop where I define many datas. At the end of it  I want to save the information related to the last 2 increments,

I do it as follows, but I get a KeyError: 65

```
for capt in dispo_ville_n.index.values.astype(int):
#bla bla bla my script, then at the end, I type this:
 nmbr_capt =capt_fonctionnels[dispo_ville_n.loc[capt,"DevEUI"],dispo_ville_n.loc[capt-1,"DevEUI"]].value_counts()
```

Can anyone help me with that ?
Thanks for advance

Comment: That is a rather dense bit of code, if you are not absolutely sure what it is doing. Try breaking apart that long chain of functions into separate lines, with diagnostic print statements in between to better see what is going on...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.